# Django Nested Relation API response

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have two models `District` and `BTS`. I want to get the response like bellow.

```
[{
    "id": 15,
    "name": "Westen",
    "page": 1,
    "expanded": false,
    "selected": false,
    "children": [{
        "id": 12,
        "name": "BTS2",
        "page": 1
    }]
}, {
    "id": 13,
    "name": "Noth",
    "page": 1,
    "children": [{
        "id": 13,
        "name": "BTS2",
        "page": 2
    }]
}]
```

**I have two Serializer**

```
class BTSSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return {
            'id': value.id,
            'name': value.bts_id,
            "page": 4,
            "expanded": False,
            "selected": False,
        }

    class Meta:
        model = BTS
        fields = ('bts_id', 'id')


class DistrictSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return {
            'id': value.id,
            'name': value.name,
            "page": 1,
            "expanded": False,
            "selected": False,
            "children": []
        }

    class Meta:
        model = District
        fields = ('name', 'id')
```

This is BTS model

```
class BTS(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    bts_id = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique=True)
    district_id = models.ForeignKey(District, related_name='districts', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    bts_type_id = models.ForeignKey(BTSType, related_name='types', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "base_stations"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bts_id
```

I changed as follows

```
class DistrictSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    bts = BTSSerializer(many=True)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return {
            'id': value.id,
            'name': value.name,
            "page": 1,
            "expanded": False,
            "selected": False,
            "children": value.bts
        }

    class Meta:
        model = District
        fields = ('name', 'id', 'bts')
```

How could I achieve this ?

Got this error

```
AttributeError at /tree_parents/

'District' object has no attribute 'bts'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/tree_parents/
Django Version:     2.2
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'District' object has no attribute 'bts'

Exception Location:     /home/samitha/workspace/techlead/tas-test/api/serializers.py in to_representation, line 45
```

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Comment: i already followed that. when i add bts to field list it says bts is not in District

Comment: show the full Traceback, but if that is the case then error is self-explanatory, add `bts` to `district`, check the drf example again

Comment: @PetarP i updated the error .

Comment: You need add `source='bts_set'`

Comment: @BearBrown to where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

better to see your `District` model, but you can try the solution:

```
class DistrictSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    children = BTSSerializer(source='districts', many=True)
    num_children = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    page = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    expanded = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    selected = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_page(self, obj):
        return 1
    def get_expanded(self, obj):
        return False
    def get_selected(self, obj):
        return False
    def get_num_children(self, obj):
        return obj.districts.count()

    class Meta:
        model = District
        fields = ('name', 'id', 'children', 'page', 'expanded', 'selected')
```

Comment: what is `bts_set` meanning ?

Comment: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `children` on serializer `DistrictSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `District` instance.
Original exception text was: 'District' object has no attribute 'bts_set'.

Request Method:

Comment: i hope a fixed, `_set` is default name for related objects https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference, but you set the `related_name` so should be `districts`. Better to change it to the `bts`.

Comment: i works well. i want to get the children count to the parent object. how could i get it ?

Comment: create model property or serialized method

Comment: `numChildren = len(children)`
`TypeError: object of type 'ListSerializer' has no len()`